# Reflow expander on resize or orientation change

Tags: highslide

I'm looking at [hs.Expander.prototype.reflow](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.reflow), and what I would like to achieve is to have the expander reflow on resize or orientation change.

Not having much luck getting it to work, though. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to apply the automatic resizing to the regular image hs.expand(), or to an hs.htmlExpand()?

Comment: A regular expander, I suppose. For images. I was basically looking to experiment whether I could get the images to refit to the viewport when the size or orientation of the viewport is changed, rather than only when advancing to the next image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only known experiment in doing this is available here:

http://highslide.com/studies/window-resize-2.html

You're not going to like it. In short, it's simply closing and re-opening the expander to adapt to the changing viewport. It's jerky, distracting, and not really usable.

(What I think you're discovering is that Highslide JS is probably the best image expander available, but it's virtually an orphan. Support is sketchy, and development has ceased. The script desperately needs some updating and rewriting. I've got a short list of things it really needs, both to address the video world and to address the mobile world, but I have little hope that any of those things will be addressed. It really is a pity.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's basically exactly what I've been wanting to see, if not the result I would like to achieve. I've been using Highslide JS very happily for a very, very long time. It's definitely not the most mobile friendly, but remains the finest lightbox for desktop browsers. I might try pairing this with debounce to see whether that makes it any nicer, if only as an experiment.